# How can I get my class to recognize this enum?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an enum I'm trying to inject into a class at an angular app.

I can't get typescript to recognize the properties of the enum and get the error `Property 'xs' does not exist on type 'appBreakpoints'`

Code:

```
// appBreakpoints.ts file
export enum appBreakpoints {
    xs = 1, // convert xs to truthy value
    sm,
    md,
    lg,
    xl,
    xxl
}

// In app.module
import { appBreakpoints } from './appBreakpoints'
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: appBreakpoints, useValue: appBreakpoints}
    ]
});

// In some service
import { appBreakpoints } from './appBreakpoints';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
class MyClass {
    constructor(@Inject(appBreakpoints) private appBreakpoints: appBreakpoints) {
        if (0 < this.appBreakpoints.xs) { // TS ERROR: Property 'xs' does not exist on type 'appBreakpoints'
            console.log('something being logged');
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get typescript to recognize the enum properties so I can use them in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to understand why you want to make a service out of this enum insted of directly using it from the service.

But the problem is that the value provided is the enum appBreakpoints (i.e. the enum class itself), whereas what you inject in your constructor is of type appBreakPoints, and is thus supposed to be an *instance* of appBreakpoints (i.e. xs, or sm, etc.).

To make your code work, you would need to change the service to

```
constructor(@Inject(appBreakpoints) private bp: typeof appBreakpoints) {
    if (0 < this.bp.xs) { 
        console.log('something being logged');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It got my code working. I have the enum in app-config file and just want to make it available to other services that might need the enum.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use angular DI for this? I guess its enough to just import the file and use the enum...

```
// In some service
import { appBreakpoints } from './appBreakpoints';

class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        if (0 < appBreakpoints.xs) {
            console.log('something being logged');
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, according to this angular/cli issue, you should use `InjectionToken` to get this working:

> You cannot use a pure type to inject, e.g. an enum or an interface. You will need to use an InjectionToken, as @jotatoledo pointed out. Please follow Angular's documentation for help on how to use tokens.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8011

https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken